# filter() a dict in python - return just the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to filter a dictionary, where I get the keys when they have a specific value, and just want to return the keys from the dict. Here is my code:

```
def smaller_than(d, value):
    result = filter(lambda x: x[1]<=3, d.items())
    return result

number_key = {35135135: 5, 60103513: 3, 10981179: 2, 18637724 : 4}
number = smaller_than(number_key, 3)
print(number)
```

There I get a result like [(60103513, 3), (10981179, 2)], but I just want to get it like [60103513, 10981179]. I think it is a easy answer but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Use a list comprehension. it takes only one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to pass `d.items()` as an iterable to `filter`. Just pass the `dict` object (same as `dict.keys()`) and filter the content based on `dict[key]` with *lambda expression* as:

```
>>> number_key = {35135135: 5, 60103513: 3, 10981179: 2, 18637724 : 4}

>>> filter(lambda x: number_key[x]<=3, number_key)
[60103513, 10981179]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may also use a *list comprehension* expression to filter your dictionary as:

```
>>> number_key = {35135135: 5, 60103513: 3, 10981179: 2, 18637724 : 4}

>>> [k for k, v in number_key.items() if v<= 3]
[60103513, 10981179]
```

Answer (score 0):

first solution, just add:

```
new_list = []
for i in number:
    new_list.append(i[0])

print new_list
```

second solution:

```
def smaller_than(d, value):
    result = filter(lambda x: x[1]<=3, d.items())
    result = map(lambda x: x[0], result)
    return result

number_key = {35135135: 5, 60103513: 3, 10981179: 2, 18637724 : 4}
number = smaller_than(number_key, 3)
print(number)
```